# Revoke permissions on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to revoke all permisions of an user on a database, but i can't get it to work.

I am doing:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE db1 FROM user1;
```

Comment: `REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE db1  FROM user;`

Comment: And what happens when you do that? Do you get an error, or just not the desired effect?

Comment: I don't get an error, i just don't get the desired effect.

Comment: Just to be clear, please edit the question to include how you tested the result, what you wanted to happen, and what actually happened. It makes it easier to understand the problem, and less likely that someone will give you an answer that doesn't apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`REVOKE ALL` refers to all the permissions on one object, not on any related objects. In this case, you are saying "all permissions which apply to the database, as a single object". The only permission which exists *at the database level* is `CONNECT`, and by default, that is granted to the special role `Public`, of which all other roles are a member.

So to deny access to a user that way, you would have to revoke CONNECT privilege from Public, and then explicitly GRANT it to the roles you *do* want to give access to.

There are a few other options that come to mind:

- Set a DENY rule for that combination of user and database in pg_hba.conf
- Revoke USAGE on all schemas in the database, so that they can connect but not access anything. I believe the `public` schema has this granted to the public role, so you will need to revoke first as with CONNECT
- Revoke all from the objects within the database. This requires multiple statements like `REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA foo FROM somebody` for different object types. You should also use `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` to make sure objects you create from now on won't be accessible.